# Use base BindingSource as derived Form datasource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, design-time, visual-inheritance

I have a base `Form` that has a public `BindingSource` property, named "BaseSource". Its `DataSource` property is set to a business object type.

I thought that if I created a derived form from it, in the designer I would have access to "BaseSource" and that it would allow me to bind the derived form's controls to my business object's properties.

Is there something special I must do so that the designer sees the "BaseSource" instance like just any other `BindingSource` object dragged into the designer's component tray?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the ideas mentioned in the comments below (thanks for the feedback) but unfortunately I couldn't make it work. I've used [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013) and two projects, one holding the base form and the business object class, the other holding the derived form. Base form exposes a protected property named *BaseBindingSource* of type `BindingSource`. In the base form's constructor, I set that base binding source's `DataSource` property to a new instance of `List<BusinessObject>`. The projects compiles without issues but in the derived form's designer I still cannot reach out to *BaseBindingSource* as an usable data source.

Making this property public didn't help either.

Comment: this is not the best option - change the modifiers property in your bindingsource on the baseform to protected...,or,provide Higher-level methods that provide the functionality you need.

Comment: @terrybozzio The functionality I need is to be able to easily bind any controls to it at design time.

Comment: @terrybozzio I just tried exposing the BindingSource as a protected readonly property but it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I think it sees it alright; however it won't appear in the object bin until you use it. Simply assign the datatsource in the properties tab and it'll appear in the bin as bOBindingspurce or whatever..

Comment: I'll try again with an overly simple project as a test. I'll post back my results here.

Comment: Well, I gave up on this. Again, thanks for your help.